# I keep getting an error, This is my first time using classes, here is my code:

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfml

The Error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SFML_lesson1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Main.cpp
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(5): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'event'
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2065: 'event' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2228: left of '.type' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2653: 'Event' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2065: 'MouseButtonPressed' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2065: 'event' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2228: left of '.mouseButton' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is ''unknown-type''
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2228: left of '.button' must have class/struct/union
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2653: 'Mouse' : is not a class or namespace name
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(8): error C2065: 'Left' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\main.cpp(47): error C3867: 'input::leftclick': function call missing argument list; use '&input::leftclick' to create a pointer to member
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is my first time doing stuff like this, I have been learning C++ in the past few weeks, but I am getting a weird error. I am using SFML following these tuts on udemy to understand the basics of game dev. I decided to write a simpler way to use the left trigger event, then to write out a long line.

Here is my **KeyEvents.h** file:

```
class input{

public:

    Event event;

    int leftclick(){
    event.type == Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == Mouse::Left;

    return true;
    }

};
```

Here is my **Main.cpp** file:

```
//Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Settings.h" // Includes the Settings.h file located in the "Header Files" folder
#include "KeyEvents.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;


int main(){
    // Declarations
    bool Playing=true; // Used for the Main loop when the game starts up
    //  The datatype holding all the events 
    Event event;

    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(Settings::WIDTH,Settings::HEIGHT), "Project"); // Creates the windows

    window.setFramerateLimit(Settings::FRAME_RATE); // Sets the Frame-rate limit
    window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(Settings::KEY_REPEATE); // Remove spamming keys
    while(Playing==true){ // Main loop


            while (window.pollEvent(event)){

                if(event.type == Event::KeyPressed){ // If a Key has been pressed! 
                        // For certain keyboard buttons it would be 'event.key.code == Keyboard::A'
                            // There are two states for the keyboard 'KeyPressed' and 'KeyRelease'

                    cout << "A Key has been pressed!\n";

                }
                 else if(event.type == Event::KeyReleased){

                        cout << "The key has just been released!\n"; // This message only pops up when they 'A' or 'a' has been released


                    }


                 if(event.type == Event::KeyReleased && event.key.code == Keyboard::Escape){ // This is for when the 'event' is closed the game will exit, by making the bool 'Playing' to false it is set to close by using the escape key

                     cout << "The Game has just been closed when Pressing the 'Escape Key'\n";
                     Playing=false;

                 }

                 if(input::leftclick){ // My custom way of knowing when the user left clicks with his/her mouse inside the class input there is a function called leftclick

                 cout << "YAY I AM LEARNING\n";


                 }


            }

        //  Logic:  


        //  Rendering:

    // Clears the window, then displays what it needs to
    window.clear();
    window.display();

    }

    window.close(); // Closes the window. when Playing is false

// Returns tto the computer that the program is running fine.
return true;
}
```

Its a weird error I guess.

Comment: Vou declare a variable "Event event;" but never assign it nor create new instance, then how you can test its value?

Comment: It looks like you have few issues. You should read the log and fix them one by one. for example [ syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'event']. It looks like you are missing a ';' somewhere.

Comment: I am not missing a ';' anywhere. I double checked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your Event class is not defined (or even declared) before it is used.
Where do you declare it?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler error says that `Event` type is not defined. You need to include header with its definition at beginning of `KeyEvents.h`. And don't forget to use namespace scope resolution:

```
#include <SFML/Event.hpp>

class input{
public:
   sf::Event event;

   // Other code
   ...
};
```

Also would like to mention that it's not recommended to use global `using` directives. Write them locally, in scope of functions.

Comment: Why is it not recommended to use global using directives? Also I get this error 1>c:\users\steven\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sfml_lesson1\sfml_lesson1\keyevents.h(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SFML/event.hpp': No such file or directory

Comment: I also have another error:'input::leftclick': function call missing argument list; use '&input::leftclick' to create a pointer to member

Comment: @StevenJGarcia Is your SFML folder is on project include path? Project properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories. Or in VC global directories: Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> Include files

Comment: @StevenJGarcia It's not recommended to use global using directives because they affect everything in translation unit scope and make namespaces useless. This could lead to unintended ambiguous names problems or even worse - to unintended type substitution when you think you are using `A`, but actually it's `n::A`.